NoClassDefFoundError running pitest in Gradle
I'm trying to add pitest to a Gradle build.  The app uses Java 11, PowerMock, and JUnit 4.  I have tried Gradle 8.4 and 8.11.1.  This app has a lot of customizations in build.gradle, mainly around constructing the classpath manually.
I have been trying to follow the instructions here.  Specifically, I have this:
plugins {
    ...
    id 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.15.0'
}

And this:
pitest {
  verbose = true
}

However, running the pitest task produces a NoClassDefFoundError:
2024-12-04T14:16:04.342-0600 [ERROR] [system.err] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pitest/mutationtest/config/PluginServices

2024-12-04T14:16:04.342-0600 [ERROR] [system.err]         at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:35)

2024-12-04T14:16:04.343-0600 [ERROR] [system.err] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pitest.mutationtest.config.PluginServices

2024-12-04T14:16:04.343-0600 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)

2024-12-04T14:16:04.343-0600 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)

2024-12-04T14:16:04.343-0600 [ERROR] [system.err]         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

2024-12-04T14:16:04.343-0600 [ERROR] [system.err]         ... 1 more

The PlugnServices class it's looking for is in the pitest-entry jar, which is not on the classpath.  Log output shows this command (edited for readability):
2024-12-04T15:00:02.388-0600 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process

'command 'C:\Program files\Java\jdk-11.0.23\bin\java.exe''.

Working directory: C:\Users\myuser\projects\myproj\proj\pin

Command: C:\Program files\Java\jdk-11.0.23\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant

-cp

C:\Users\myuser\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.pitest\pitest-command-line\1.15.0\519ee413fd060273d10215b1a56da2021f0f0aba\pitest-command-line-1.15.0.jar

org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport

As you can see, only the pitest-command-line jar is there.
Running gradle dependencies on this project reflects that:
pitest - The PIT libraries to be used for this project.

\--- org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.15.0

I have a working project to compare against using Spring Boot 3, Java 17, and JUnit 5.  Running gradle dependencies produces a different tree:
pitest - The PIT libraries to be used for this project.

+--- org.pitest:pitest-command-line:1.15.0

|    \--- org.pitest:pitest-entry:1.15.0

|         +--- org.pitest:pitest:1.15.0

|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0

|              \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0 -> 3.17.0

\--- org.pitest:pitest-junit5-plugin:1.2.0

You can see that pitest-entry is there.  When I run the pitest task on this project, the classpath does include all those jars.  I have no idea why they are different.  The versions of the pitest plugin in both projects are the same.
What can I do to get the pitest dependencies added?
thanks

While I do not know why the dependencies were not automatically added, I worked around the problem by adding them manually:
pitest(group: 'org.pitest', name: 'pitest-command-line', version:'1.15.0')
pitest(group: 'org.pitest', name: 'pitest-entry', version:'1.15.0')
pitest(group: 'org.pitest', name: 'pitest', version:'1.15.0')

